# Android Error on PlayStore

Tags: android

Any ideas of this errror is showing me the PlayStore:

```
     *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> {{myPackageName}} <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000007e204  [anon:libc_malloc:94700000]
  #01  pc 000000000004d72d  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android6Parcel14freeDataNoInitEv+32)
  #02  pc 000000000004d705  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android6ParcelD1Ev+4)
  #03  pc 00000000000b8899  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7androidL25android_os_Parcel_destroyEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassx+6)
  #04  pc 00000000005d11c7  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Binder.restoreCallingIdentity [DEDUPED]+102)
  #05  pc 0000000000e023ed  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Parcel.finalize+76)
  #06  pc 00000000002a30f1  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize+96)
  #07  pc 00000000002a335b  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal+466)
  #08  pc 00000000002a2c17  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+70)
  #09  pc 00000000001ee141  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+64)
  #10  pc 00000000003dd861  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #11  pc 00000000003e1dd5  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
  #12  pc 00000000000ac4ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
  #13  pc 0000000000332f5d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
  #14  pc 0000000000333dd1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
  #15  pc 0000000000351641  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
  #16  pc 0000000000047db7  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
  #17  pc 000000000001b0a5  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 hours of searching and testing, I found that this error was, apparently caused by Location and GSON [look here](https://github.com/e-mission/e-mission-data-collection/issues/49) , the app start to crash randomly with no advice and no log error.

I was saving Location on SharedPreferences and using GSON to serialize it, bad idea; now just saving each attribute of location and that did the trick.